# unable to use C-x o to switch frame focus while in term frame

Tags: key-bindings, frames

I cannot use C-x o to switch to another frame while in a term frame. Here are the steps to replicate the issue:

1. press `C-x 2` to split frame
2. press `C-x o` to change focus to new frame
3. press `M-x term RETURN RETURN` to switch new frame to term window with bash
4. press `C-x o` to return to previous frame

`*Messages*` says `C-x o is undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html

`C-c char` -- "This is equivalent to `C-x char` in normal Emacs. For example, `C-c o` invokes the global binding of `C-x o`, which is normally `other-window`."